# Floating point multiplication with repetative addition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, computational-complexity

I am developing a toy microservices application to show off opentracing stuff. Its a basic calculator. So far I have an 'add' service and a 'mul' service. The 'add' service adds two numbers together that it receives in an array - the 'mul' service then sends the 'add' service a bunch of calls to perform repetative addition in order to find the answer.

4×4 =
0+4=4
4+4=8
8+4=12
12+4=16

Obviously, when we have a decimal multipler we're going to have a problem - could I have some jack and jill explanations on how this might be efficiently accomplished?

I'm also planning 'sub' and 'div' services to operate in similar ways. I would like to avoid doing any arithmetical operations in the 'mul' service this should all be done in 'sub' and 'add' perhaps I'll also implement an external 'count' service :)

Fundementally I am attempting to break down every arithmetic operation that one might conduct on a simple digital calculator into count, add and subtract operations.

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: You simply can't do this. There's no way to multiply by $0.5$ using repeated addition. It simply isn't repeated addition.

Comment: You are going to need two more operations: shift left and shift right. which moves the decimal point one location right or left. Then you shift the decimal until you have an integer, apply your addition-based multiplication, then shift the decimal the same distance in the other direction in the result. Of course, shift also provides a faster means of multiplication.